# JS Query: How to retrieve the value of click in JS visualization in a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, linker, click, visualization

I have a Hierarchical Edge Bundling visualization in JS. When I click on 1 value I want its name to be displayed on the table.

I am using the following but am unable to retrieve the value when it is dynamic. If I hardcode 1 value I am able to display it.

Please help!

```
.on("Click",func(){retrieve the value of click here})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this to register the event for dynamically added content:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.SomeSelector' , function(){ } );
```